# Intel mnemonic to machine code converter library

Tags: libraries, assembly, intel

I'm trying to do the following: take a single IA32 instruction in the Intel syntax (such as `ADD EAX, EBX`) and produce the corresponding machine code for this instruction. Is there some small library, preferably open source, that can do this for me?

Comment: You could probably extract that part from, say, NASM, and turn it into a library -- but I don't know of one that's already built to do exactly that (and it's not clear how it would work in some cases, such as jmp instructions, which normally need a series of instructions so the assembler can compute the offset to the target).

Comment: Jerry, for JMPs I'd like to be able to specify the target address and the resulting object code should imply include the address verbatim.

Comment: Do you want to write a small assembler, or do you need to have an assembler in your program?

Comment: @Thorbjørn I need the assembler inside my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with FASM.
There is a sample GUI application distributed with [FASM DLL](http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=6239)
Or, you can use Python interpreter, with [Python binding for FASM DLL](http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=12105)

Comment: Is there a version for linux too, Abyx?

Comment: @Frederick, DLL? You can try Wine.

Comment: I guess I could use Wine if nothing else works. But I think I should try and hack NASM into a library first. Thanks anyway :)